# Background Music in wordpress, with ON and OFF maunual

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I need to have background Music in my website, With user oN and OFF functionality, I have used a javascript, but the problem is, when the user switch off the music, then on reloading the page, the music starts again, is there any plugin available to accomplish this task.

Comment: Just add a cookie that stores the on/off funtionality, and have your auto-play check for that cookie. No need for a plugin for something so simple. Plus...auto-play music? What's your site's address so I can blacklist it in my browser?

Comment: @Marc thanx for the help, and no need to blacklist the website, it will be a smooth music.

Comment: One person's smooth is another person's fingernails on blackboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Soundmanager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) is your friend.

It is easy to configure install and also has many options.

It works like [this](http://www.truthabouttrees.org/) example site.

It has a excellent examples when you download it. First try to run the examples and check for the example that might best suite your requirements.

One more important thing to remember is the paths in these JS files. The path names to the files it uses is little weird so look out for the path names if you get errors and you should be good to go. :)